# Upload songs from iTunes library to iOS

Tags: ios

I would like to upload songs from a local iTunes library to my server via an iOS application. Apple provides access to iTunes library contents from iOS by using the following info key:

> Privacy – Media Library Usage Description

Due to this, I am able to read the list of songs on my iPhone, but I would like to upload those songs.

Comment: Apple doesn't allow this. MAJOR privacy concerns.

Comment: Thanks @charlieFish, any official link regarding this?. I searched apple docs but not able to get the link.

Comment: The fact that it's not on the Apple Docs is enough to show that it isn't possible. Apple keeps VERY great documentation. If it isn't in there, strong likely hood it doesn't exist. They can't write about every feature that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie Fish.

Comment: Awesome. Just posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Apple doesn't allow this due to major privacy concerns. Normally if Apple's documentation doesn't mention a feature it isn't supported by Apple, so therefor probably unlikely to be able to do it without using privacy APIs or jailbreaks.